# how to retrieve a string between to same charecter

Tags: javascript, string

I know how to use substring() but here I have a problem,  I'd like to retrieve a number between two "_" from a unknown string length. here is my string for example.

7_28_li

and I want to get the 28. How can I proceed to do so ?

Thanks.

Comment: You can find the `_` locations with `indexOf` cannot you? And after you do - you can use `substring`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Regex

```
'7_28_li'.match(/_(\d+)_/)[1]
```

The slashes inside match make it's contents regex.

- `_`s are taken literally
- `(` and `)` are for retrieving the contents (the target number) later
- `\d` is a digit character
- `+` is "one or more".

The `[1]` on the end is accesses what got matched from the first set of parens, the one or more (`+`) digits (`\d`).

### Loop

```
var str = '7_28_li';
var state = 0; //How many underscores have gone by
var num = '';
for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (str[i] == '_') state++;
    else if (state == 1) num += str[i];
};
num = parseInt(num);
```

Probably more efficient, but kind of long and ugly.

### Split

```
'7_28_li'.split('_')[1]
```

Split it into an array, then get the second element.

### IndexOf

```
var str = "7_28_li";
var num = str.substring(str.indexOf('_') + 1, str.indexOf('_', 2));
```

Get the start and end point. Uses the little-known second parameter of indexOf. This works better than lastIndexOf because it is guaranteed to give the first number between `_`s, even when there are more than 2 underscores.

Comment: It looks like you incorporated Meredith's answer at the bottom of yours in an edit. It might be helpful to give them some credit for this.

Comment: @Brad I actually came up with it independently.

Answer (score 1):

First find the index of `_`, and then find the next position of `_`. Then get the substring between them.

```
var data = "7_28_li";
var idx = data.indexOf("_");
console.log(data.substring(idx + 1, data.indexOf("_", idx + 1)));
# 28
```

You can understand that better, like this

```js
var data = "7_28_li";
var first = data.indexOf("_");
var next  = data.indexOf("_", first + 1);
console.log(data.substring(first + 1, next));
# 28
```

**Note:** The second argument to [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf#Parameters) is to specify where to start looking from.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way to do it is to call `split` on your string, with your delimiter ("_" in this case) as the argument. It'll return an array with 7, 28, and li as elements, so you can select the middle one.

`"7_28_li".split("_")[1]`

This will work if it'll always be 3 elements. If it's more, divide the length property by 2 and floor it to get the right element.

```
var splitstring = "7_28_li".split("_")
console.log(splitstring[Math.floor(splitstring.length/2)]);
```

I'm not sure how you want to handle even length strings, but all you have to do is set up an if statement and then do whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you know there would be 2 underscore, you can use this

```
 var str = "7_28_li";
 var res = str.substring(str.indexOf("_") +1, str.lastIndexOf("_"));
```

If you want to find the string between first 2 underscores

```
var str = "7_28_li";
var firstIndex = str.indexOf("_");
var secondIndex = str.indexOf("_", firstIndex+1);
var res = str.substring(firstIndex+1, secondIndex);
```